# llamar un metodo desde una DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Como puedo llamar un metodo desde un `DilogFragment`, el problema es que en este `DialogFragment` lo uso para generar un cuadro de dialogo donde ingreso dos datos que se almacenan en un archivo hasta esa parte no tengo problema, se guarda correctamente todo.

Pero lo que quiero hacer es que una vez que esos datos se guarden se tiene que ejecutar un metodo que leera los nuevos datos, pero al hacer la instancia al metodo me da un **error:

> **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileInputStream android.content.Context.openFileInput(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Este es el codigo de mi clase principal donde tengo el metod que quiero llamar, el metodo se llama **refrescar()**, este metodo esta al final del codigo:

```
package com.example.enriq.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private String archivo = "sesion.obj";
    private String carga = "parquimetro.obj";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        try{
            ObjectInputStream objInput = new ObjectInputStream(openFileInput(carga));
            Registro_parqueo persona = (Registro_parqueo) objInput.readObject();
            objInput.close();
            TextView luffy = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.muestrario);
            luffy.setText(persona.toString()+"\n");

            //Toast.makeText(Principal.this, "Archivo cargado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Error al leer el archivo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            Log.e("Principal", "Error clase no encontrada");
        }


        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.ususesion);
            try {
                ObjectInputStream objInput = new ObjectInputStream(openFileInput(archivo));
                Usuario persona = (Usuario) objInput.readObject();
                objInput.close();
                text.setText(persona.toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sesión inicia con exito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al cargar el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error clase no encontrada");
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        //este metodo es para obtener el id del menu de los
        //tres puntos
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.exportar){
            //onClickRadio(view);
        }else if(id == R.id.sesion){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    /*public void onClickAlerta(View view){
        listaParqueos lista = new listaParqueos();
        lista.DialogoAlerta(view);
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.iniciotap){
            /*Parqueos parqueos = new Parqueos();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.exp, parqueos).commit();*/
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setSubtitle("Parqueos");

        }else if(id == R.id.noticiastap){
            //Traemos al fragmento de noticias
            /*configuracion confi = new configuracion();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            //vamos a sustitur el contenedor del activity main por un nuevo fragment
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.exp, confi).commit();*/
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setSubtitle("Preferencias");


           /* getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(android.R.id.content, new ConfiguracionesFragment())
                    .commit();*/
        }
        //Este codigo nos permite mostrar que menu esta seleccionado
        //para poder identificar que menu esta en uso
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
//Este es el metodo al que quiero llamar
   public void refrescar(){

        try{
            ObjectInputStream objInput = new ObjectInputStream(openFileInput(archivo));
            Registro_parqueo persona = (Registro_parqueo) objInput.readObject();
            objInput.close();
            TextView luffy = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.muestrario);
            luffy.setText(persona.toString()+"\n");
        }catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(this,"No quedo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            Log.e("Principal", "Error clase no encontrada");
        }

    }
}
```

y esta es mi clase Dialogo que extiende de un DialogFragment, en el metodo que se llama **onclicguardarpersona()** intento llamar al metodo que esta en mi clase principal que se llama **refrescar()**:

```
package com.example.enriq.myapplication;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_APPEND;
import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

/**
 * Created by Enriq on 30/01/2018.
 */

public class Dialogo extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
    private ArrayList<Registro_parqueo> lista;
    private String archivo = "parquimetro.obj";
    View view;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        //builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
        View MyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);
        final EditText matricula = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.parqueo);
        final EditText clienesillo = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.cliente);
                // Add action buttons
        builder.setView(MyView)
                .setPositiveButton("Registrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        onClickGuardarPersona(matricula.getText().toString(),clienesillo.getText().toString());

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Dialogo.this.getDialog().cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }

    public void onClickGuardarPersona(String matricula, String clienesillo) {
        try{

            ObjectOutputStream objOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(getActivity().openFileOutput(archivo, MODE_PRIVATE));
            objOutput.writeObject(new Registro_parqueo(matricula,clienesillo));
            objOutput.close();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Parqueo registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Principal principal = new Principal();
            principal.refrescar();

        }catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error al guardar el parqueo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Intenta llamarlo de esta manera.  ((Principal) getActivity()).refrescar(); En vez de hacer una instanncia de la clase Principal.

Comment: @DiegoLoL  Me funciono muchas gracias, si se llamo al metodo de otra clase.

Comment: De nada para eso estamos, para ayudarnos @Kike hatake.

Comment: intenta ponerla como respuesta y que el OP la marque, ya que puede servir para otros usuarios que nisiquiera leen los comentarios! @DiegoLoL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para llamar al método perteneciente a la clase Principal desde

> onClickGuardarPersona(String matricula, String clienesillo)

, debemos llamar al Activity:

> ((Principal) getActivity()).refrescar();

En vez de crearnos una Instancia de esa clase.

Comment: Genial!!!! Muchas gracias!!! Es justo lo que necesitaba!!! :-)